# Kubernetes node OOM and Node Allocator's systemReserved setting

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

We are having an issue with nodes going into NotReady state.
We implemented metricbeat to watch the per-process cpu/mem usage, and filebeat to grab kubelet logs and we see at the point of crashing:

- kswapd spikes
- network and basic system services seem to drop out.
- ssh listening but doesnt process request

It looks like we are entering swap hell where the server is swapping out mmap files from executables, then they need to be brought back in off disk when the process is to be run again.

I’ve had a good look at the Node Allocator project.
The annoying thing with this is that you need to specify SystemReserved - which as they warn is an Upper Limit on memory for System Services.

i.e. you could easily run into the same OOM hell situation in the systemreserved cgroup...

I can see that we have the -cgroups-per-qos flag set and we have the kubepods cgroup created with all the pods in it.

I assume it would be easy to apply a memory limit to the kubepods cgroup that’s e.g. 2GB less than the total RAM on the machine.

The problem i have is that kubelet’s Available Memory calculation is still going to look at the memory on the entire Node and not just what’s in the kubepod’s cgroup…

Has anyone found a workaround to get kubelet to calculate Available Memory based on the kubepods cgroup, without needing to turn on Node Allocatable?

Comment: "The annoying thing with this is that you need to specify SystemReserved - which as they warn is an Upper Limit on memory for System Services" - Who is saying that? SystemReserved is reserved memory, not limit memory, where reserverd=guaranteed. And it does not set limit for system services but sets limit for pods to MAXmemory - systemreserved, check it yourself, set SystemReserved to some value and check `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/kubepods.slice/memory.limit_in_bytes`, what do you see?

Comment: from the docs "Be extra careful while enforcing system-reserved reservation since it can lead to critical system services being CPU starved, OOM killed, or unable to fork on the node." 
Check it the paragraph in full - it functions as an upper limit.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable. 
Your calc is correct, for the kubepods memory.limit_in_bytes but systemReserved remains a limit

Comment: actually thanks Matt you've just triggered a memory. the instructions also say _Note that Kubelet does not create --system-reserved-cgroup if it doesn't exist. Kubelet will fail if an invalid cgroup is specified_. did you create a systemReserved cgroup manually? does your kubelet fail without a valid systemReserved cgroup?  if this works then maybe i have my solution

Comment: I did not create any systemReserved cgroup. I only added `systemReserved: memory: 2G` in kubelet config file.

Comment: awesome i'll give this a try and post back. thanks!

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: ahhh not going to get to implement this one until after new year ;(